# How to dynamically change a ContentControl's Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a content control with a template I would like to dynamically change while the software is running. I am new to WPF and am struggling how to do this. So far I've meddled with StaticResource and RelativeSource. Here is the code:

One of my templates:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HomeTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" Grid.Row="0" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                     Width="100" Height="100" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="HOME PAGE" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="50" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

ContentControl I am trying to bind the template to. Currently it is directly set to the template but I want it to be set to a property in my C# code so I can dynamically change it.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="content1" Grid.Row="1"
                        Template="{StaticResource HomeTemplate}"
                        Visibility="Visible">
        </ContentControl>
```

Here is my ViewModel where I want to be able to change the template:

```
public class TabsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabData> Tabs { get; set; }
    public Command cmdAddTab { get; set; }
    public string PageTemplate { get; set; }

    public TabsViewModel()
    {
        var sampleData = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(x => new TabData()
        {
            TabText = "TAB",
        });

        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabData>(sampleData);
        cmdAddTab = new Command(AddTab);
        PageTemplate = "StaticResource HomeTemplate";
    }

    private void AddTab()
    {
        Tabs.Add(new TabData()
        {
            TabText = "NEW TAB"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want the template of your contentcontrol or the datatemplate of it's content?

Comment: @Andy I think ContentControl because I want to swap out totally different ControlTemplates

Comment: @Andy Perhaps it is a ContentTemplate I need to use

Comment: I think it's more likely a datatemplate, but then I don't really know what your aim is here. A common pattern is to associate a simple template or a usercontrol with a viewmodel using datatype= type of viewmodel. Whenever the ui gets a vm of that type it templates it out into controls. That is used in viewmodel first navigation as well as itemscontrols such as a tabcontrol where you want to bind a collection of viewmodels and you want different ui based on what they are.

Comment: @Andy. I want to change content within a ContentControl depending on what tab I've pressed.

Comment: OK. So there's a tabcontrol and separately this contentcontrol? IE This content is not items in the tabcontrol? Exactly the same data no matter which tab is pressed but with a different template?

Comment: Another candidate could be another tabcontrol but re-styled so you just see the tab item matching the first.

Comment: Hey @Andy. I've made my own tab items out of listviewitems instead of using the normal tab control for various reasons. I need to display different content  depending on whichever listviewitem is selected

Comment: @DavidAndrewThorpe: You've only posted a HomeTemplate. Where is the other template? How do you know when to apply which template?

Comment: @mm8 I'm currently concerned with being able to bind a template dynamically from code before I worry about deciding which of a number of templates to bind.

Comment: @DavidAndrewThorpe: You should change the type from `string` to `ControlTemplate` then to begin with.